# Was "than" omitted in "1000 times [than] their actual size"?

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases, modifiers

In a dictionary, I happen to stumble upon a phrase:

> bacteria magnified to 1000 times their actual size

I think “than” was omitted from the phrase, but I'm not sure. I want to know the structure of the phrase as well.

First, I have assumed that NP (or DP) is analyzed in PP like the followings.

> [to [1000 times their actual size]NP(or DP)]PP
>
> [1000 times(quantifier) their(determiner) actual(adjective) size(noun)] NP(or DP)

The preposition *to* means *as far as something*.

Am I right?

Second, I try to put *than* in the phrase:

> [bacteria [magnified to 1 000 times]AP]NP [than their actual size]PP.

Here is the meaning of *than*:

> *Than* is used as a function word to indicate difference of kind, manner, or identity, which is used especially with some adjectives and adverbs that express diversity.

> E.g. anywhere else than at home

Which one is right? In addition, which test is there in syntax for those for whether or not those are correct?

Answer (score 4):

"1000 times" doesn't need an extra *than*.

*than* is use for comparison on what's on the left and what's on the right.

"1000 times" already mentions the difference. "times" is a noun, therefore "than" is a conjunction. So "than" is not needed here.

Some example of using "than" would be:

> bacteria zoomed in 1 000 times bigger than their actual size

You would need "bigger". "than" requires a *comparative adjective* before it, and "bigger" *is* one of the most often used comparative adjectives.

Comment: I have a question. you said than is a conjunction. Then, How do I understand the structure of [bigger than their actual size]. This pattern shows *adjective and noun phrase* in the preposition phrase. Can I get an evidence that the pattern is right?

Comment: @bak1936 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Than#:~:text=Than%20is%20a%20grammatical%20particle,similar%20description%20between%20two%20predicates.

Comment: Oh my mistake. How did it happen? Sorry. I mean *This pattern shows adjective than noun phrase"

Comment: @bak1936 Tbh, 1000 times without "than" is good enough.

Comment: @bak1936 As the answer states, you only need "than" with a *comparative adjective*, like "bigger". "1000 times" is not a comparative adjective

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you found in the dictionary is correct, the sentence you gave is wrong.

*1000 times* is neither an adjective nor an adverb but a noun, and does not modify anything. The "than" is used as a conjuction here.

No, "than" should not be inside the sentence. If you want to use "than", it should be

> bacteria is magnified 1000 times bigger than its actual size

When using "than", you need to have a word with "er" as an adverb or adjective. As what @U12-forward has mentioned, this "bigger" is a *comparative adjective*, which is a *must* when using "than".

> Comparative adjectives are used to compare differences between the two objects they modify (larger, smaller, faster, higher). They are used in sentences where two nouns are compared, in this pattern: Noun (subject) + verb + comparative adjective + than + noun (object).
>
> From [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative/%23:%7E:text%3DComparative%2520adjectives%2520are%2520used%2520to,than%2520%252B%2520noun%2520(object).&ved=2ahUKEwiYt8ua-OX3AhVXUGwGHU3cCbYQFnoECAkQBQ&usg=AOvVaw0qefQZGM0AJgeHNWIefoqG)

So it follows the following:

> Bacteria (subject) + magnified (verb) + bigger than (comparative adjective) + actual size (object)

Answer (score 0):

> *"Bacteria magnified to 1000 times their actual size."*

This sentence is grammatically correct.

We can rewrite the sentence in the following way without any change in meaning :

> *Bacteria magnified to 1000 times **as big as** their actual size.*

However, we can rewrite the sentence using **bigger than** with a slight difference in meaning :

> *Bacteria magnified to 1000 times **bigger than** their actual size.*

Now, let me explain the difference in meaning by giving a simple example :-

> (A) [400 = 100 + 100*3]: *"400 is three times bigger than 100."*

> (B) [300 = 100*3] : *"300 is three times as big as 100."* OR *"300 is three times 100."*

Comment: I have read something like the (A) somewhere in English Language Learner. But I have't found out "than" is "and" or "plus", so I'm not sure. Even though "than" is changed into "and", the changed (A) doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I have explained it as clearly as possible. But maybe you don't know what you want.

Comment: Personally, I think ELL SE should abolish bounties. Their utility is doubtful, in my opinion.